# How can I stop annoying spelling suggestions in snippets suggestions popup in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

How can I stop these annoying spelling/grammar suggestions from showing up in VS Code?

[image]

I'm pretty sure they just randomly started showing up and not sure why. Don't even know what terms to google for the setting to apply to settings.json. Thanks!

Comment: Those are the `Suggestions` in `Files->Preferences->Settings->Text Editor`

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll select it as the solution.

Comment: Those are specifically `Word Based Suggestions` which can be separately disabled without affecting all your object suggestions.  Look in the Settings for `Word Based Suggestions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the `Suggestions` in `Files->Preferences->Settings->Text Editor`